# Can't list a job for Hong Kong because of location handler

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, location

Our address is Unit 2206, 22/F, Wu Chung House, No. 213 Queen’s Road, Wanchai, Hong Kong, China HK SAR. But service can't parse it and the best option it provides is that:

[image]

But with this address I can't list my job offer, probably it did not see Hong Kong as a city, but believed it is a country instead.

What can I do to bypass this?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the pin? I *think* it'll update the address box to what Google thinks is the address for the location of the pin. It could be both the city and the country should be listed, so *Hong Kong, Hong Kong* would work perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I tried both variants you suggested before came here with this issue :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this should be resolved for this particular case: in the Address field, copy and paste "213 Queen's Road East, Wan Chai, Hong Kong" into the field. You should be able to post your job from there.

As you guessed, Hong Kong is a particularly gray area when it comes to geocoding, but geocoding is also an issue that we're working through as a whole right now. There's a new geocoding framework that we're testing now where even cases like this will pass through as we'd expect. In the near future, you'll see less and less of this.

Let me know in a comment if this works, and I'll mark this as resolved.

Comment: Yep. It is working for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... We're looking into this, in the meantime, if you enter "Central, Hong Kong" the parser will accept the input and you will be able to post your job. More to follow...

Comment: Hm... I tried it few times. Now I literally copy and paste "Central, Hong Kong". Same error for me. I am trying to preview, I did not pre-purchase listing it it make any difference.

Comment: @IlyaBelikin hmm that works for me. Did you tab out of the address field so the address was updated before re-submitting? Preview does not matter.

Comment: My session expired so I just fill form again. This time it accept it. I will try to reproduce this error.

Comment: Sorry, I missed second answer above. Now it just works. Thank you for you help!